# webpack-bundle-analyzer Interpretation of Bundle Report

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am trying to understand what I can do to optimize my Angular (4+) app that is being bundled using Webpack. I was smart enough to follow [this tutorial](https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack) to generate a useful bundle report from my production build, however, I don't quite understand what the report is showing me.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

It looks like `aws-sdk.js` is being duplicated in at least three bundles, and the `tinymce.js` stuff is in a couple separate bundles... does this mean I am importing the third-party node_modules in an inefficient way?

Also, the `material.es5.js` file (the angular material design module) is in a few modules... what's up with that? It's true that I am importing the material design module into multiple lazy-loaded modules, but I thought Angular was [smart enough not to duplicate code](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice)?

Any advice or insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What the report is showing is that you have a main bundle called `scripts` & a handful of dynamically generated smaller bundles (called `chunks`) also you have a `vendor` bundle which only contains `@angular`

It's really hard to give an answer to something like this without seeing the code, the webpack config & what are you trying to achieve exactly but here are some steps that can help.

You should create a `vendor` bundle that has all your main dependencies like `tinymce`, `angular`, `aws-sdk`, `material.es5`, etc... which are most probably not going to change much so you can make the browser cache this bundle. To do this you need to add an extra entry like this

```
    entry: {
       scripts: 'path/to/scripts.js',
       vendor: [
          'tinymce',
          '@angular',
          'aws-sdk',
          etc...
       ],
    },
```

You will also need the `CommonChunksPlugin` like this

```
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor'],
      minChunks: Infinity,
    }),
```

This might give you good start I think, on how to fix some of the issues.